# Compute gradients for each time step of tf.while_loop

Tags: python, tensorflow, while-loop, backpropagation

Given a TensorFlow `tf.while_loop`, how can I calculate the gradient of `x_out` with respect to all weights of the network for each time step?

```
network_input = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None])
steps = tf.constant(0.0)

weight_0 = tf.Variable(1.0)
layer_1 = network_input * weight_0

def condition(steps, x):
    return steps <= 5

def loop(steps, x_in):
    weight_1 = tf.Variable(1.0)
    x_out = x_in * weight_1
    steps += 1
    return [steps, x_out]

_, x_final = tf.while_loop(
    condition,
    loop,
    [steps, layer_1]
)
```

*Some notes*

1. In my network the condition is dynamic. Different runs are going to run the while loop a different amount of times.
2. Calling `tf.gradients(x, tf.trainable_variables())` crashes with `AttributeError: 'WhileContext' object has no attribute 'pred'`. It seems like the only possibility to use `tf.gradients` within the loop is to calculate the gradient with respect to `weight_1` and the current value of `x_in` / time step only without backpropagating through time.
3. In each time step, the network is going to output a probability distribution over actions. The gradients are then needed for a policy gradient implementation.

Comment: Are you sure you are interested in `x_out` and not `x_final`?

Comment: Yes, the network is a self-enrolling model like [image captioning](https://cs.stanford.edu/people/karpathy/cvpr2015.pdf). The network outputs a probability distribution over actions in each time step, until it decides to be "done". I need the gradient of each of the outputs (actions) and not only the last one.

Comment: Are you trying to create a new variable on each `tf.while_loop` iteration? That cannot be done with TensorFlow. With your current code you are creating only two variables, one used for `layer_1` and another one used on every loop iteration.

Comment: No, I don't want to create new variables in every iteration. I simply want to backpropagate through time: Compute the gradient of `x_out` with respect to `weight_0` and `weight_1` for every time step.

Comment: So why are you declaring `weight_1 = tf.Variable(1.0)` inside the loop? Were your intention to actually `tf.get_variable`?

Comment: I think it shouldn't make a difference, since "while_loop calls `cond` and `body` exactly once" ([copied from the TensorFlow API](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/while_loop))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't ever call `tf.gradients` inside `tf.while_loop` in Tensorflow based on [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/14101) and [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/9450), I found this out the hard way when I was trying to create conjugate gradient descent entirely into the `Tensorflow` graph.

But if I understand your model correctly, you could make your own version of an `RNNCell` and wrap it in a `tf.dynamic_rnn`, but the actual cell 
 implementation will be a little complex since you need to evaluate a condition dynamically at runtime.

For starters, you can take a look at Tensorflow's `dynamic_rnn` code [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.7/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn.py).

Alternatively, dynamic graphs have never been `Tensorflow`'s strong suite, so consider using other frameworks like `PyTorch` or you can try out `eager_execution` and see if that helps.

Comment: Have you found a workaround for Conjugate Gradient entirely in TF (and avoiding eager execution)?

Comment: I have, yes. It's non-trivial. Check out [this repository](https://github.com/tensorforce/tensorforce). They have a pretty robust implementation.